# Filter files by timespan into single table

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to return all files within a folder's sub-folders that have a last write time within a particular time span. I would like these files to be in one table only. I want to see the filename, filesize and LastWriteTime.

I have this code so far:

```
$timestartstr = "2020-09-16 07:00:00"
$timestart = [datetime]::ParseExact($timestartstr, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", $null)
$timeendstr = "2020-09-16 09:00:00"
$timeend = [datetime]::ParseExact($timeendstr, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", $null)

$dir = "path\to\parent\folder"

Get-ChildItem -Recurse $dir 
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $timestart -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $timeend} 
    Format-Table LastWriteTime, Name
```

This is not filtering by the timespan I've specified, the gt/lt doesn't appear to be doing anything, and also it returns a separate table for each sub-directory.

I'm relatively new to PS and I can't work out how to achieve what I want.

**UPDATE**
See the comments below the accepted answer for how to exclude folder names from the results

Final working script:

```
$timestartstr = "2020-09-16 07:00:00"
$timestart = [datetime]::ParseExact($timestartstr, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", $null)
$timeendstr = "2020-09-16 09:00:00"
$timeend = [datetime]::ParseExact($timeendstr, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", $null)

$dir = "path\to\parent\folder"

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File $dir |
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $timestart -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $timeend} |
        Select-Object Name,LastWriteTime,Length
```

EDIT
The above `Length` property is in bytes, not very readable, below is an update for that line, to return the size in MB as a `Double`.

```
Select-Object Name,LastWriteTime,@{N='SizeMB';E={[double]('{0:N2}' -f ($_.Length/1kb))}}
```

Comment: you don't have any `|` symbols at the end of the "supposed to be a pipeline" lines. [*grin*]

Comment: also, here in CST timezone, it is still the 15th, not the 16th. [*grin*]

Comment: Haha, yes I originally had the `|` symbols but removed them while trying to get the desired behaviour :) I'm in New Zealand, hence the date ;)

Comment: ah! [*grin*] with those items dealt with, your code works for me to get the items in the desired time range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mr Lee_Dailey pointed out, you are missing the glue between your commands - the pipe `|` character. You're also missing the length property and I recommend using `Select-Object` over `Format-Table` to retain the items as proper objects.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $dir |
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $timestart -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $timeend} |
        Select-Object Name,LastWriteTime,Length
```

Edit:

To exclude directories, you can simply apply the `-File` parameter to `Get-ChildItem`

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse $dir |
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $timestart -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $timeend} |
        Select-Object Name,LastWriteTime,Length
```

Comment: Cheers, one thing I forgot to specify in the question, is how to exclude this from returning folder names?